# Spread a table in a date time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hello everyone it's been some days that I use sql to make analysis and I meet all kinds of problems that I solves thanks to your forum.

Now I'd like to create a view that recuperates the interval of time and shows in detail the dates in this interval.

I have the following table:

[image]

And I want to create the view that displays the result:

[image]

For example in the player1 MyTable to play five days from 01/01/2012
  to 05/01/2012. So the view displays 5 lines for player1 with the date 01/01/2012, 02/01/2012, 03/01/2012, 04/01/2012, 05/01/2012.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a common table expression that give you the date range ( i have created a date range of the current month but you can choice another range) :

```
WITH DateRange(dt) AS
(
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01') dt
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-31')
)

SELECT dates.dt AS DatePlaying, PlayerName 
FROM MyTable t
JOIN DateRange dates ON dt BETWEEN t.BeginDate AND t.DateEnd
ORDER BY PlayerName, DatePlaying
```

Comment: Can you please teach me something [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6baa8/2) by doing some corrections?

Comment: Ok, see the updated answer, the common table expression work only with date within a month ...

Comment: Thanks and +1.. My Updated and Corrected Fiddle is [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6baa8/6)

Comment: The only problem is that there might be a limit on the recursion level for the data range.  This might not work so well when the dates are spanning years.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer but that dont work it show an error message du to converting value is out of limite .

Comment: What version of SQL are you using ? It works you can try out this code on SQL Fiddle, see the link posted by  Pankaj Garg

Comment: In case the start year is 1960 and end year is 2012. Shall I create records for 72 years first in Common Table Expression first and then it's join with other table?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is simply to create an enumeration table to add values to dates:

```
with enumt as (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
               from mytable
              )
select dateadd(d, e.seqnum, mt.DateBegin) as DatePlaying, mt.PlayerName
from MyTable mt join
     enum e
     on enumt.seqnum <= e.NumberOfPlayingDay
```

The only purpose of the "with" clause is to generate a sequence of integers starting at 1.

Comment: Thx for your answer but that show an error message. i fixed it like that : with enum as (select NumberOfPlayingDay,row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
               from v_mytable
              )
select dateadd(d, e.seqnum, mt.DateBegin) as DatePlaying, mt.PlayerName
from v_MyTable mt join
     enum e
     on seqnum <= e.NumberOfPlayingDay

But that shot a wrong result : 2012-01-02 Player1
2012-02-04 Player2
2012-01-02 Player3
2012-01-03 Player1
2012-02-05 Player2
2012-01-03 Player3
2012-01-04 Player1
2012-02-06 Player2
2012-01-04 Player3